# Is Cardano the only platform with 100% decentralized block production?

Tags: decentralization, governance

Inspired by [this comment](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/71/to-what-extent-does-cardanos-off-chain-governance-in-the-form-of-a-board-of-d#comment59_71) saying that decentralization of block production is overused in the way people market Cardano online, I was curious to see if any other platforms have achieved this. I know that other platforms such as Tezos do have some level of on-chain governance, but not necessarily 100% decentralized block production as Cardano does.

- When I search "decentralized block production" in quotes, [I get over 1000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22block+production+decentralization%22&biw=1832&bih=887&ei=nvaIYMTeMZqutQatrJnABQ&oq=%22block+production+decentralization%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANQzhBY4hRggRdoAXACeACAAXCIAY8CkgEDMi4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjEpYOpnqDwAhUaV80KHS1WBlgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5), which seem to ***all be about Cardano.***
- When I search the same thing but only allowing results before 2021, [I get only 6 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22block+production+decentralization%22&biw=1832&bih=887&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1990%2Ccd_max%3A2020&ei=d_aIYLTODNrKtQa8zoD4Ag&oq=%22block+production+decentralization%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANQxaIBWP6pAWDUqwFoAXAAeACAAV2IAboBkgEBMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj05ZGWnqDwAhVaZc0KHTwnAC8Q4dUDCA4&uact=5) and they all (literally 100% of them) seem to contain the word Cardano or ADA or IOHK.

Is it really the case that no other platform has managed to achieve 100% decentralized block production?

Answer (score 8):

This all depends on how you view it. For instance, consider Bitcoin. Bitcoin has 100% decentralized block production, since no central authority owns Bitcoin and can regulate its block production. One might argue that the large mining companies that control a majority of block production makes this decentralization somewhat dubious. To be fair, the same thing happens with Cardano. Consider how much of the Cardano block production the Binance stake pools control.

To be honest, I am not sure there is a straightforward answer to your question. I would say that other chains have achieved full decentralization; however, Cardano is one of the most decentralized (if not the most) due to the numerous stake pools operated by individual community members.